# How to overlay scatterplot on grouped bar chart with ggplot2 on R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar chart thats grouped by subject group and experimental condition. I want to overlay each participant's data point on top of each bar chart. When I tried adding the points in, I was able to sort the points by absent/present condition but not by young/older adult. Is there a way to group the points by both variables and have them sit on top of a bar graph thats already grouped. [this is what I have now, but I want the points to be separated into distinct groups by subject group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiJDc.png)

```
ACC3 <- read_xls(path="raw_data/ACC3.xls") #loading data file

#setting the order of variables on graphs (from alphabetical to custom)
ACC3$Condition <- factor(ACC3$Condition, c("Absent", "Present")) 
ACC3$Group <- factor(ACC3$Group, c("Young Adult", "Older Adult")) 

ACC3 %>%
    ggplot(aes(fill=Group, y=accuracy, x=Condition)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", width = 0.8, stat = "summary", fun = "mean", color="black", size = .8)+
    facet_grid(cols = vars(Condition), scales = 'free') +
    scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Young Adult", "Older Adult")) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom='errorbar', color='black', position=position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.2, linewidth = 0.8) +
    geom_point(position = position_jitter(0.3), stat="identity", alpha = 0.8)
```

I have also tried doing the facet by subject group instead of condition and that helped me sort dots into their respective categories, but the graph then isnt grouped in the way I want (like in the first picture)[the dots are grouped correctly, but the bars are not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mVjc.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to align the points with bars you do dodge them too by using `position = position_jitterdodge(...)` instead of `position_jitter`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

ACC3 <- data.frame(
  Condition = sample(c("Absent", "Present"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Group = sample(c("Young Adult", "Older Adult"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  accuracy = runif(100, 90, 110)
)

ACC3$Condition <- factor(ACC3$Condition, c("Absent", "Present"))
ACC3$Group <- factor(ACC3$Group, c("Young Adult", "Older Adult"))

ggplot(ACC3, aes(fill = Group, y = accuracy, x = Condition)) +
  geom_bar(
    position = "dodge", width = 0.8, stat = "summary", fun = "mean",
    color = "black", linewidth = .8
  ) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Condition), scales = "free") +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Young Adult", "Older Adult")) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = mean_sdl, geom = "errorbar", color = "black",
    position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.2, linewidth = 0.8
  ) +
  geom_point(
    position = position_jitterdodge(0.3, dodge.width = .8),
    alpha = 0.8
  )
```

[image]